# How do I split an Azure Web App Service into multiple 'sub web app services'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a large monolithic Azure Web App Service (written in C# ASP.NET MVC5), comprised of a few discrete subapps that have little to do with one another other than sharing a domain name.

I'd like to split the monolithic webapp into several 'subservice' web apps: separate projects, with new projects potentially being in a different langauge (eg. nodejs).

It seems like I'd need a master Azure webapp that serves as the router? Or is there a better approach?

So e.g. if a request comes to http://www.example.com/subapp1, it should be served by SubApp1, but a request to http://www.example.com/subapp2 should be served by SubApp2.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this with Azure Web App services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use virtual directories to do the division. This blog post has a good overview of how to set-up and deploy virtual directories for web apps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx.

Essentially, you would first create the main site and publish to it. Then using the portal, create the virtual directories. Then, for individual projects you can publish to each of those virtual directories.

Comment: another way I experimented with was setting up a reverse proxy webapp like http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/, but virtual directories seems like a better solution